# AsyncTask Not Running

Tags: java, android

I have an AsyncTask that downloads a bunch of images, as seen below:

```
class DownloadHelper extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public Context mContext;
    private DBHelper mDatabase;

    DownloadHelper(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDatabase = new DBHelper(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        List<Exercise> mExercises = mDatabase.getExercises();
        for (int i = 0; i < mExercises.size(); i++) {
            Exercise e = mExercises.get(i);
            Log.d("path", e.getImage_start());
            saveFile(e.getLink_start(), e.getImage_start());
            saveFile(e.getLink_end(), e.getImage_end());
        }
        return null;
}

    private void saveFile(String url, String path){
        //region Save Bitmap To File
        URL mURL = null;
        try { mURL = new URL( url ); }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) { Log.d("Error", "ce url de cacat smr yo niki nu merge");  e.printStackTrace();}
        HttpURLConnection mConn = null;
        try { mConn = (HttpURLConnection) mURL.openConnection(); mConn.setDoInput(true); mConn.connect(); }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        Bitmap mBitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream mInput = mConn.getInputStream();
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mInput);
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        //endregion

        //region Save Bitmap
        if (mBitmap != null){
            try {
                FileOutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(path);
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mOutput);
                mOutput.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) { Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage()); }
        }
    }
}
```

and it is called in a function like this:

```
public void initialize(){
    PermissionManager mManager = new PermissionManager() {};
    mManager.checkAndRequestPermissions((Activity) mContext);
    downloadExercises();
    //region Create Exercises Folder To Store Images
    File mFolder = mContext.getDir("exercises", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!mFolder.exists()) mFolder.mkdir();
    Log.d("path", mFolder.getAbsolutePath());
    //endregion
    DownloadHelper mDownload = new DownloadHelper(mContext);
    mDownload.execute();
}
```

However, when i debug the app, i have a breakpoint on `mDownload.execute()` and then some other ones in the `doInBackground()`, but the app never gets to the async task.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the logs? You can also try 'DownloadHelper mDownload = new DownloadHelper((Activity) mContext);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. The Async was running but it seems that the downloadExercises() function added the exercises to the database AFTER the async would call getExercises() in order to download the images and therefore it didnt do anything. The solution i found was to prompt the user with a dialog to download the images AFTER the download and insertion of exercises was completed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I believe you need to pass in null parameters when executing your async task:

`mDownload.execute((Void) null);`

If this doesn't help, perhaps your if statement is not passing, therefore your method is never run?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

```
class DownloadHelper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
String response=null;

//** Do Your code here and must the result declare to response **// 

return response;
}
}
```

In your main class after declare Asyntask then get the return value

```
DownloadHelper mDownload = new DownloadHelper();
mDownload.execute(mContext);
```

then add this line

```
String get_return=mDownload.get();
```